# Is a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ that's $L^2$ integrable necessarily bounded?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on a homework problem and if I can prove this claim then I am finished.  Intuitively the answer should be yes, but I can't think about how I would attempt to rigorously prove this.  I have an entire function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and I know that $|f|^2$ is integrable over $\mathbb{C}$.  I want to say this implies that $f$ is bounded and hence the $0$ function by Liouville's theorem.

The idea is that if $f$ isn't bounded, then its modulus has to approach infinity as $|z|\rightarrow\infty$ for some particular direction.  But this "direction" should be on a set that doesn't have measure $0$ and hence the integral of $|f|^2$ wouldn't be finite, which would contradict my claim.

Comment: Liouville theorem only implies that $f$ is constant not $0$.

Comment: Yeah but integrable and constant implies 0.

Comment: @C.Dubussy: But there are not a lot of functions which are constant and square-integrable.

Comment: That's right :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Write $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n.$ Compute the integral of $|f|^2$ over $D(0,R),$ using polar coordinates and Parseval's theorem.

Comment: Great, thanks!!